# What does BOOST_TEST_PASSPOINT do?

Tags: c++, boost-unit-test-framework

Can anyone tell me what the function of `BOOST_TEST_PASSPOINT` is? The [official documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/test-output/BOOST_TEST_PASSPOINT.html) links to the wrong page, and [has for the past four years](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3392).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yikes!  It's bizarre that the documentation would be so difficult to fix.

The macro `BOOST_TEST_PASSPOINT()` is a parameter-less equivalent to [`BOOST_TEST_CHECKPOINT()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/test-output/BOOST_TEST_CHECKPOINT.html).

If a test error happens, the line of the last checkpoint will printed.